# Finding matches between an input string and a fixed set of strings

Tags: python, string, search, tree, string-matching

I need to compare an input string to multiple strings which I'll refer to as fixed strings, and you can assume the latter won't change during execution. Comparison disregards letters with special characters, only letters from A to Z, but case insensitive. I need to try to match my input string to the start of every one of the fixed strings, even if not all characters match, not unlike [approximate string matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching).
In other words, want to identify overlap between each word from input string and every word from fixed strings. I'm particularly interested in full matches, e.g. (`love`) and (`love`) in the second example below.

*I don't actually want to display matches*, instead do some calculations based on them: whenever there is a full match, I want to increment a counter with a certain value, and whenever there are partial matches, I want to increment with another value. The counts are what I am really looking for, but I'd need to match the strings first.

###### Here's an illustration of how to match:

If my fixed strings are "`apple`", "`bullcrap`", "`tomato`", "`apricot`", I should be able to search for "`Applecrab`" and get the following matches:

```
(Apple)crab App(l)ecrab Applecrab   (Ap)plecrab 
    
(apple)     bul(l)crap  tomato      (ap)ricot
```

I also should be able to do multiple input words, as in:

fixed strings: "`i love books`", "`book fair`"; input string: "`I love`"; matches:

```
(I) I    I      |  love  (love)  l(o)ve
(i) love books  |  I     (love)  b(o)oks
   
I     I     |  l(o)ve love
book  fair  |  b(o)ok fair
```

---

A naive, simplified algorithm for comparing two strings would look like this:

```
inputString = "love".lower()
fixedString = "love".lower()
lenComp = min(len(inputString), len(fixedString))
counter = 0
for i in range(lenComp):
    if inputString[i] == fixedString[i]:  # Partial match
        counter += 1  
if counter == len(inputString):  # Full match
    counter += 10
print(counter)  # 14
```

Since the number of fixed strings isn't very small, the solution should employ a decent data structure. I was thinking about trees: a [prefix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) seems to be a good fit, but it wouldn't help with loose matches in the middle of a string, e.g. `l(o)ve` and `b(o)oks`, neither would the [Aho–Corasick algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm). I don't think [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) can help either. What are some data structures/algorithms I could use to achieve this?

---

I'm tagging this with Python since I'll probably use it, but I'm not too concerned with implementation right now.

Comment: How do you get to `bul(l)crap` from `Applecrab ` and `banana` ?

Comment: Sorry, just fixed it.

Comment: Do you actually want to compare each input word to every word in the fixed strings, or do you want to identify fixed strings with some overlap for each input word and just show those?  If the set of fixed strings is large enough to require a clever data structure surely you don't want to display all the empty matches all the time as shown in your question?

Comment: do you mean the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)?

Comment: @TMBailey I want to identify overlap between each word from input string and every word from fixed strings. I'm particularly interested in full matches, e.g. (love) and (love), but I don't actually want to display these matches, instead do some calculations based on them. I've edited the question to further explain.

Comment: It will be much easier to help you if you show a short code snippet that tries to do the _core_ of what you want to do but need help with instead of outlining the whole project.  If the sticking point is how to match aligned characters in two words, a baseline to beat might involve `[c1==c2 for c1, c2 in zip(w1, w2)]` where w1 and w2 are two word strings.

Comment: Please can you clarify in the question whether the *counts* are all you need to get out, or whether you need to know which positions within each probe word do or do not match the corresponding letter positions within each of the fixed string?  This distinction could make all the difference for the kind of data structures to be considered for optimal performance.

Comment: I thought that limiting the discussion to a higher abstraction level would be better, but that's ok. I've further clarified my question and introduced a code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

just an idea to explore, maybe a modified prefix tree will do the job, you will need add each string and all it's substrings and keep track of the position of each character in other places in the tree.

for example: ABD, BAD, RCDB can be added to the prefix tree as follows

[image: example prefix tree]

say you want to find matches for CAB, you would need a search function that takes the string and starting position

```
search(CAB,0)  -- this will try to find a first node C with position 0 but won't find one
```

you then would remove the C and search for AB with position 1

```
search(AB,1)
```

that will find the A node which says that A is present in position 1 in the BAD node and you would follow that link.  etc...

EDIT:

you would create the tree by starting with the root node and adding all letters of the alphabet to that node.  each letter would have a position dictionary

```
node = { ...
   pos : { }
}
```

initially the position dictionary would be empty for all letters, i.e. they are not being used either as a starting or middle character in any words

to add the word ABD the logic would go something like

```
Letter 0 - A
    update pos dict for A to be {0 : []}
    the contents of the array for pos 0 are not used (i think)
Letter 1 - B
    add node B under A
    update pos for node B under root to {1 : ['A']}
Letter 2 - D
    add node D under B
    update pos for node D under root to {2 : ['AB']}
    note: it is set to AB so it helps you walk down the 
          tree quicker when doing a search
```

next we add BAD

```
Letter 0 - B
    update pos for node B to be {0:[], 1:['A']}
Letter 1 - A
    add node A under B
    update pos for Node A under root to be {0:[],1:['B']}
letter 2 - D
    add node D under B of the chain BA
    update pos for node D under root to be {2 : ['AB','BA']}
```

to search for the word CAD you would

- check node C under root at the top level this has empty pos dict {}
  so no word starts with C so we can skip C
- move to the next char check node A under root for pos = 1, it has pos = {0:[],1:['B']} so take the array for key 1 and this tells you that you will find a A under the root B node, walk the tree from here to find the longest match this will give you A(BD)
- move to next char D, check the root node D for pos 2, it has {2 : ['AB','BA']}, so you walk the tree to find the matches AB(D) and BA(D)

EDIT 2:

this is a very simple (and inefficient) python implementation:

```
import string, pprint

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)

root = {x:{} for x in string.ascii_lowercase}

def add_word(word):
    def _add_word(node, hist, word, pos):
        if word[0] not in node:
            node[word[0]] = {}
        root[word[0]].setdefault("pos",{}).setdefault(pos,set()).add(hist+word[0])
        if len(word) == 1:
            node[word[0]]['is_word'] = True
        else:
            _add_word(node[word[0]], hist+word[0], word[1:], pos+1)

    _add_word(root, "", word.lower(), 0)


def search(word):
    found_words = set()
    def find(node,prefix,word,pos,result):
        # print("prefix:",prefix,", word:",word,", pos:", pos,", result:",result)
        if prefix:
            find(node[prefix[0]], prefix[1:], word, pos, result+prefix[0])
        else:
            if node.get('is_word',False): found_words.add(result)
            for x in string.ascii_lowercase:
                if x in node: find(node[x], "", "", pos, result+x)

    for i in range(len(word)):
        if i in root[word[i]].get("pos",{}):
            for prefix in root[word[i]]["pos"][i]:
                # print("calling find with: ", prefix, word, i)
                find(root,prefix,word[i:],i,"")

    print(f"result for {word}:", found_words)


add_word('apple')
add_word('bullcrap')
add_word('tomato')
add_word('apricot')
# pp.pprint(root)
search('applecrab')
search('dove')
```

the output of running the above is:

```
result for applecrab: {'apple', 'bullcrap', 'apricot'}
result for dove: {'tomato'}
```

Comment: That makes sense, but I'm worried about how would it be possible to keep track of the position of each character spread around the tree, and what exactly do you mean by all its substrings (in your example, where is `CD`, a substring of `RCDB`?). Could you clarify your answer?

Comment: @AtilioA, i've edited my answer to clarify further, one additional thing you need to be careful of is not to add entries to the array which are not required.  for example when adding the word BADLY you don't need to 'BA' to the position array of D as it is already there for BAD

Comment: This is better, thanks. However, "check the root node `D` for pos 2, it has `{2 : ['AB','BA']}`, so you walk the tree". Why exactly would you walk down the tree, what's the relation? And through which branch? The root of the prefix tree alone can accommodate 26 nodes (A-Z). 
I'm also assuming that you would only traverse it if `pos` is smaller than the length of the original input string.

Comment: you check root node D for pos 2 because D is in pos 2 of the word CAD (0 based counting), that tells you that D is in the second position of the tree starting with root node A -> B then you will find D,  this simplifies the search because the root node A will have up to 26 child nodes any one of them might have a child node D, so when creating the original prefix tree we add "AB" to the rood node D for position 2 so that we can go there directly by walking the tree without having to do a search. and you do the same for BA, walk through node B then A then you will find another D

Comment: i added a simple python implementation to show how this can be implemented

Comment: (I was about to leave this comment before the edit, so I'm going to do it anyway): I'm finally getting a grasp of your idea. However, how do I simplify searches with a "number of nodes away" if I still have to access nodes by letters and not a numerical index?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237736/discussion-between-atilioa-and-someonerandom3142).